# Use a TemporaryQueue on client-side for synchronous Request/Reply JMS with a JBoss server bean

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I have a MDB running on JBoss 7.1, and a simple Java application as a client on another machine. The goal is the following:

1. the client sends a request (ObjectMessage) to the server
2. the server processes the request and sends back a response to the client (ObjectMessage again)

I thought to use a TemporaryQueue on the client to listen for the response (because I don't know how to do it asynchronously), and the JMSReplyTo Message's property to correctly reply back because I should support multiple independent clients.

This is the client:

```
public class MessagingService{

private static final String JBOSS_HOST = "localhost";
private static final int JBOSS_PORT = 5455;
private static Map connectionParams = new HashMap();

private Window window;

private Queue remoteQueue;
private TemporaryQueue localQueue;

private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private Connection connection;
private Session session;



public MessagingService(Window myWindow){
    this.window = myWindow;
    MessagingService.connectionParams.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, JBOSS_PORT);
    MessagingService.connectionParams.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, JBOSS_HOST);
    TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration =  new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), connectionParams);  
    this.connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) HornetQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);
}


public void sendRequest(ClientRequest request) {
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        this.session = connection.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        this.remoteQueue = HornetQJMSClient.createQueue("testQueue");
        this.localQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(remoteQueue);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(localQueue);

        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
        message.setObject(request);
        message.setJMSReplyTo(localQueue);
        producer.send(message);

        ObjectMessage response = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive();
        ServerResponse serverResponse = (ServerResponse) response.getObject();
        this.window.dispatchResponse(serverResponse);

        this.session.close();

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO splittare e differenziare
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I'm having troubles writing the server side, as I cannot figure out how to establish a Connection to a TemporaryQueue...

```
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            Destination replyDestination = message.getJMSReplyTo();
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
            ClientRequest request = (ClientRequest) objectMessage.getObject();

            System.out.println("Queue: I received an ObjectMessage at " + new Date());
            System.out.println("Client Request Details: ");
            System.out.println(request.getDeparture());
            System.out.println(request.getArrival());
            System.out.println(request.getDate());
            System.out.println("Replying...");

                            // no idea what to do here
                            Connection connection = ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? 

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer replyProducer = session.createProducer(replyDestination);
            ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse("TEST RESPONSE");
            ObjectMessage response = session.createObjectMessage();
            response.setObject(serverResponse);
            replyProducer.send(response);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a valid message for this Queue MDB");
        }

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out what am I missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question here.. You should look at how to create a Connection inside any Bean.

you need to get the ConnectionFactory, and create the connection accordingly.

For more information, look at the javaee examples on the HornetQ download.

In specific look at javaee/mdb-tx-send/ when you download hornetq.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MDBMessageSendTxExample",
               activationConfig =
                     {
                        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/testQueue")
                     })
public class MDBMessageSendTxExample implements MessageListener
{
   @Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

   public void onMessage(Message message)
   {
     Connection conn = null;
     try
     {

        // your code here...

        //Step 11. we create a JMS connection
        conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        //Step 12. We create a JMS session
        Session sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        //Step 13. we create a producer for the reply queue
        MessageProducer producer = sess.createProducer(replyDestination);

        //Step 14. we create a message and send it
        producer.send(sess.createTextMessage("this is a reply"));

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally
     {
        if(conn != null)
        {
           try
           {
              conn.close();
           }
           catch (JMSException e)
           {
           }
        }
     }
  }
```